# Zoom in points in scattered plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two sets of data points

```
s_pos = [8.8333, 12.8033 , 27.4410 , 30.4982 ,42.8710 ,46.0770,.......]
mux = [ 0.604598, 0.840701, 1.556915, 1.731411, 2.575856 ,3.158237,........]
```

I made a scattering plot as following:

```
a =s_pos
b =mux

plt.scatter(a, b, s=1, c='r')
plt.show
```

a and b has 620 data points, due to the large number of data i cant see clear individual points,

is there any way that i can zoom in specific part of the plot so i can check the individual points without removing any data ?

Comment: Don't you just mean change the axis limits to zoom in? In that case, there is `plt.gca().set_xlim([x_min,x_max])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center visualization, you should set it centered into datapoints range. Please see [plt.xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [plt.ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)

Otherwise, interactive matplotlib has zoom tool in toolbar:

[image]